# Duplicate R.class after renaming package name for my Android Studio Flutter app

Tags: flutter

Tried renaming my Android Studio flutter app package, and it is tunring out as a mess. How can I solve this issue?

Build is failing with the error message:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:multiDexListDebug'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Error while merging dex archives: 
     Type com.xxxxx.R is defined multiple times: 
....\AndroidStudioProjects\xxxx\build\app\intermediates\compile_and_runtime_not_namespaced_r_class_jar\debug\R.jar: D8: Type com.xxxx.R is defined multiple times: ....\AndroidStudioProjects\xxxx\build\app\intermediates\compile_and_runtime_not_namespaced_r_class_jar\debug\R.jar:com/xxxx/R.class, ....\AndroidStudioProjects\xxxx\build\app\intermediates\javac\debug\classes\com\xxxx\R.class

     Learn how to resolve the issue at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
```

Comment: Turned out I had an unnecessary directory in /app/src/main/java that I could just simply delete...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to run `flutter clean` in the terminal first. Or remove `/build` directory by yourself manually.

Answer (score 0):

1. On terminal type `flutter clean`
2. `Restart VSCode`
3. Run `flutter get package`

Answer (score 0):

this happens because the library you are using uses the same dependences.

**SOLUTION 1**

1. in VSCode Search `(Ctrl+Shift + P)`
2. in your error com.xxxxx.R. `search` for keywords from that error.
3. If there are the same dependences, it means that there are `duplicate dependences`.
4. Solution: Delete one of the package you are using.

**SOLUTION 2 (Recommended)**

1. in VSCode Search `(Ctrl+Shift + P)`
2. in your error com.xxxxx.R. `search` for keywords from that error.
3. Find a library that uses the same dependences, then update to the `latest package version`

4.This solution will keep the library you are using without deleting it

Answer (score 0):

Try `flutter clean && flutter get package`

And try to use a package https://pub.dev/packages/change_app_package_name

Steps:

```
dev_dependencies: 
  change_app_package_name: ^1.0.0
```

Update dependencies

```
flutter pub get
```

Run this command to change the package name.

```
flutter pub run change_app_package_name:main com.new.package.name
```

(like `flutter pub run change_app_package_name:main com.example.app`)